# Study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n \ge 1} \sin \frac{1}{n^{5/4}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I have to show whether the series

$$\sum_{n \ge 1}\sin \frac{1}{n^{5/4}}$$

is convergent or not.

This is what I tried, but I am not sure if it's correct:

We [know](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proof-that-sin-x-x-for-all-positive-real-numbers):

$$\sin x \le x, \hspace{1cm} \forall x \ge 0$$

So then

$$\hspace{6cm} \sin \frac{1}{n^{5/4}} \le \frac 1{n^{5/4}}, \hspace{.5cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{3cm}(1)$$

By the [generalized harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence), we also know

$$\hspace{7cm} \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{5/4}} \hspace{.25cm} \text{convergent} \hspace{3cm} (2)$$

Now, using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can conclude by the [First Comparison Test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/SeriesCompTest.aspx) that the series

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \sin \frac{1}{n^{5/4}}$$

is convergent.

Is this correct?

Comment: It looks good. The limit comparison criterion also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote that $\displaystyle\sin\left(\frac1{n^{5/4}}\right)\leqslant n^{5/4}$, what you should have written was that $\displaystyle\sin\left(\frac1{n^{5/4}}\right)\leqslant\frac1{n^{5/4}}$.

Besides, the comparison test is for series of non-negative numbers. So, you should add to your proof that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\frac1{n^{5/4}}\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)\implies(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\sin\left(\frac1{n^{5/4}}\right)>0.$$

Comment: You're right, I made a typo there. Sorry for that. And yes, I see now that I also have to show that the terms of the series are non-negative, which is not obvious at first glance. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.